# Cannot launch EC2 instance due to CpuOptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch an EC2 instance from a Launch Template, and I get an error that "the t2.micro instance type does not support specifying CpuOptions."

However I can't see where it is that I have specified any CpuOptions.

I must note (in case it makes a difference) that the Launch Template I'm using was based on a Spot instance, that was also a t2.micro.

Please advise.

[image: Launch Template Advanced Options]

Comment: have you created template from existing instance or created template from scratch?

Comment: Created template from exisiting instance

Comment: Check my solution, if it helped do accept it as solution to your problem so that it helps others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

> Launch Template I'm using was based on a Spot instance, which was also a t2.micro.

probably this is the issue,try creating a new template from scratch, i.e. manually selecting the AMI and instance type, etc.

note:- cputions is used by cloudformation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-launchtemplatedata-cpuoptions.html